# Nested filter search in Javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

The search functionality requirement is such that when the search input matches with the `categories.name` or inside `categories -> dishes -> dish.name` the output should be the `categories.name`.

Below is the JS data -

```js
[
  {
    name: "Tikka",
    img: "paneer malai tikka.jpg",
    categories: [
      {
        isActive: true,
        isDeleted: false,
        _id: "61a22648521aa07d718745b6",
        name: "Tikka",
        dishes: [
          {
            isActive: true,
            isDeleted: false,
            _id: "61a22648521aa07d718745b7",
            name: "paneer malai tikka",
            img: "paneer malai tikka.jpg",
            type: "veg",              },
          {
            isActive: true,
            isDeleted: false,
            _id: "61a22648521aa07d718745b9",
            name: "panner jaitoni tikka",
            img: "jaitooni paneer tikka.png",
            type: "veg",
          },
          {
            isActive: true,
            isDeleted: false,
            _id: "61a22648521aa07d718745bb",
            name: "chicken pahadi tikka",
            img: "chicken pahadi tikka.jpeg",
            type: "non veg",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        isActive: true,
        isDeleted: false,
        _id: "61a22648521aa07d718745f2",
        name: "Tikka",
        dishes: [
          {
            isActive: true,
            isDeleted: false,
            _id: "61a22648521aa07d718745f3",
            name: "lehsuni fish tikka",
            img: "lehsuni fish tikka.jpg",
            type: "non veg",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

FilterSearch.js

However below function is returning output with duplicate output.

```js
let filteredData = [];
categories.forEach((category) =>
  category.categories.forEach((subcategory) =>
    subcategory.dishes.forEach(dish => {
      if (dish.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput)) {
        filteredData.push(category);
      };
    }
    )
  )
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you need more information regarding this.

Comment: What's wrong with changing `filteredData.push(category);` to `filteredData.push(category.name);`?

Comment: What's the expected output here?

Comment: Input will be `categories name` & `dishes name inside categories` - Output will be only `categories name`

Comment: It's usually good to show a few sample tests so folks can get a sense of what your requirements are. It's a bit ambiguous with only one element in the input array. Your filtering algorithm seems correct, if a bit awkward (`filter`/`some` would be clearer), so I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just prevent duplications in the first place by checking if already exists?

```js
var categories = [{
  name: "Tikka",
  img: "paneer malai tikka.jpg",
  categories: [{
      isActive: true,
      isDeleted: false,
      _id: "61a22648521aa07d718745b6",
      name: "Tikka",
      dishes: [{
          isActive: true,
          isDeleted: false,
          _id: "61a22648521aa07d718745b7",
          name: "paneer malai tikka",
          img: "paneer malai tikka.jpg",
          type: "veg",
        },
        {
          isActive: true,
          isDeleted: false,
          _id: "61a22648521aa07d718745b9",
          name: "panner jaitoni tikka",
          img: "jaitooni paneer tikka.png",
          type: "veg",
        },
        {
          isActive: true,
          isDeleted: false,
          _id: "61a22648521aa07d718745bb",
          name: "chicken pahadi tikka",
          img: "chicken pahadi tikka.jpeg",
          type: "non veg",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      isActive: true,
      isDeleted: false,
      _id: "61a22648521aa07d718745f2",
      name: "Tikka",
      dishes: [{
        isActive: true,
        isDeleted: false,
        _id: "61a22648521aa07d718745f3",
        name: "lehsuni fish tikka",
        img: "lehsuni fish tikka.jpg",
        type: "non veg",
      }, ],
    },
  ],
}, ];

let filteredData = [];
var searchInput = "a"
categories.forEach((category) =>
  category.categories.forEach((subcategory) =>
    subcategory.dishes.forEach(dish => {
      if (dish.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput)) {
        if (filteredData.indexOf(category)==-1) {
          filteredData.push(category);
        }
      };
    })
  )
)

console.log(filteredData)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important}
```